# How to return all values from the first row of a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

The top of my spreadsheet has some keywords that dictate which column I will be searching under. To start this process I am trying to read the first row into an array and then step through the array until I find the right value. My problem is that my array length is showing up as 1, which means I'm obviously doing something terribly wrong.

I call this function from a trigger onEdit(e). My spreadsheet isn't terribly interesting, it's 10 columns and 100 rows and has 2 values in the top row.

```
function SearchMe(e) {

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();  
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  var headerRng = sheet.getRange('1:1');
  var headerValues = headerRng.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < headerValues.length; i++) {
      if(headerValues[i] == "status") {
         var listenCol = i+1;
         break;
      }
  }  
}
```

Any ideas why headerValues.length always returns 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- In your script, you retrieve values from the range of "1:1". This means that the values of all columns at row 1 are retrieved. And value retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array.

  - In this case, `headerValues.length` is 1. And `headerValues[0].length` is the number of all columns.

#### Modified script:

Please modify the for loop as follows.

```
for (var i = 0; i < headerValues[0].length; i++) { // Modified
    if(headerValues[0][i] == "status") { // Modified
       var listenCol = i+1;
       break;
    }
}
```

or

You can also replace above script as follows.

```
var listenCol = headerValues[0].indexOf("status") + 1;
```

Both script can be retrieved the same result.

#### Note:

- If you want to use `listenCol` at outside of the for loop, when it thinks of the scopes, `listenCol` of `var listenCol = i+1;` should be declared before the for loop.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thank you for such a thoughtful response. You not only explained 2 dimensional arrays to me but I'm taking the indexOf function instead because it's far more elegant for what I need. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tommy Wu I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.